# Dedicated Server Tutorials

Tags: windows-server-2008, hosting, web-hosting

I have never setup a dedicated server before except at my house but nerver attached a domain name to my ip address. I will be using windows 2008, iis7 and asp.net, sql server express 2008. I need some tutorials that will guide through the whole process. i already checked google which was some help but they were low quality tutorials.

If you can suggest some books I can buy that would be good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a learning hurdle that I think a lot of us struggle with.  You can Google your way to fame and fortune (quick - but cheap and incomplete), you can take a pile of classes / read manuals (expensive - but direct and thorough) ... but the middle ground is somewhat lacking.

I can offer my impression on the first route, as I'm a bit of a self-taught creature.  You've already identified your major components, and you'll find a large variety of online walkthroughs for installing each of them.  After it's set up, running, and hardened against the Internet, you're ready to start opening up the needed ports in your firewall, and pointing those IP addresses to that firewall.  Again, you'll find tutorials for your firewall hardware (or software) and DNS provider (I think the DNS tag here has some pretty exhaustive information).

Comment: I should mention, O'Reilly books tend to be above average.  http://oreilly.com/store/series/nutshells.html

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need to set things up is in TechNet - it's not spelled out in a simple form like a book would be but there's lots of guides that will take you through set-up and configuration of Windows, IIS & SQL Server.  Taking the time to read them will give you far more useful information and advanced options than you'd get from  a quickie tutorial.

'Attaching a domain name' is just a case of pointing the A record for your domain to your server's public IP Address (make sure you've got a good firewall set-up correctly in-front of it).

Above all, if it's not a mission critical server just playing with it (maybe stick VMWare or Virtual Server on to make testing images easier) is the best way to learn.

Are there any specific aspects that you need help with?